# How to Extract Parts of String in Shell Script into Variables

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I am trying to do the following in sh.

Here's my file:

```
foo
bar
Tests run: 729, Failures: 0, Errors: 253, Skipped: 0
baz
```

How can I pull the 4 numbers into 4 different variables? I've spent about an hour now on sed and awk man pages and I'm spinning my wheels.

Comment: What's the precise format of the file? Is there a single significant row in the file? Are the numbers always in-order?

Comment: The file will be variable but the row with Tests will always be there; thats the significant row.  The numbers in that row will always be there, in that format.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use a more capable shell with built-in regex support rather than `/bin/sh` and needing to use external tools for the extraction. I mean, yes, this can be done in pure POSIX sh, but you're going to be taking a performance hit for the startup time for awk/sed/whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Adopting my prior answer to use the heredoc approach suggested by @chepner:

```
read run failures errors skipped <<EOF
$(grep -E '^Tests run: ' <file.in | tr -d -C '[:digit:][:space:]')
EOF

echo "Tests run: $run"
echo "Failures: $failures"
echo "Errors: $errors"
echo "Skipped: $skipped"
```

---

Alternately (put this into a shell function to avoid overriding "$@" for the duration of the script):

```
unset IFS # assert default values
set -- $(grep -E '^Tests run: ' <in.file | tr -d -C '[:digit:][:space:]')
run=$1; failures=$2; errors=$3; skipped=$4
```

Note that this is only safe because no glob characters can be present in the output of `tr` when run in this way; `set -- $(something)` usually a practice better avoided.

---

Now, if you were writing for bash rather than POSIX sh, you could perform regex matching internal to the shell (assuming in the below that your input file is relatively short):

```
#!/bin/bash
re='Tests run: ([[:digit:]]+), Failures: ([[:digit:]]+), Errors: ([[:digit:]]+), Skipped: ([[:digit:]]+)'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
    run=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    failed=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    errors=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    skipped=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
  fi
done <file.in
```

If your input file is *not* short, it may be more efficient to have it pre-filtered by grep, thus changing the last line to:

```
done < <(egrep -E '^Tests run: ' <file.in)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of the input file, you can capture the output of `grep` in a here document, then split it with `read` into four parts to be post-processed.

```
IFS=, read part1 part2 part3 part4 <<EOF
$(grep '^Tests run' input.txt)
EOF
```

Then just strip the unwanted prefix from each part.

```
run=${part1#*: }
failures=${part2#*: }
errors=${part3#*: }
skipped=${part4#*: }
```

Comment: Nice. Very nice. I need to start reaching for that technique more often.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there is only one line starting with `Tests run:` in your file, and that the file is named `foo.txt`, the following command will create 4 shell variable that you can work with:

```
eval $(awk 'BEGIN{ FS="(: |,)" }; /^Tests run/{ print "TOTAL=" $2 "\nFAIL=" $4 "\nERROR=" $6 "\nSKIP=" $8 }' foo.txt); echo $TOTAL; echo $SKIP; echo $ERROR; echo $FAIL
```

---

`echo $TOTAL; echo $SKIP; echo $ERROR; echo $FAIL` is just to demonstrate that the environment variable exists and can be used.

The awk script in a more readable manner is:

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "(: |,)" }

/^Tests run/ {
    print "TOTAL=" $2 "\nFAIL=" $4 "\nERROR=" $6 "\nSKIP=" $8
}
```

`FS = "(: |,)"` tells awk to consider "`:`" or "`,`" as field separators.

Then the `eval` command will read as a command the result of the awk script and as such create the 4 environment variables.

---

**NOTE:** due to the use of `eval`, you must trust the content of the `foo.txt` file as one could forge a line starting with `Tests run:` which could have commands thereafter.

You could improve that bit by having a more restrictive regex in the awk script: `/^Tests run: \d+, Failures: \d+, Errors: \d+, Skipped: \d+$/`

The full command would then be:

```
eval $(awk 'BEGIN{ FS="(: |,)" }; /^Tests run: \d+, Failures: \d+, Errors: \d+, Skipped: \d+$/{ print "TOTAL=" $2 "\nFAIL=" $4 "\nERROR=" $6 "\nSKIP=" $8 }' foo.txt); echo $TOTAL; echo $SKIP; echo $ERROR; echo $FAIL
```

Comment: If you're going to use `eval` here, I'd suggest (strongly!) filtering for only numeric values, so an attacker can't insert code into your repository that puts `Tests run: $(rm -rf /)` -- or something that downloads and runs shellcode -- into your test suite's output. Being able to do a privilege escalation from checking hostile code into a git repo to running code inside live infrastructure is not a Good Thing.

Comment: you are right, eval can be evil, I will update my answer with a warning

Comment: (on a different point, all-caps variable names are bad practice; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace).

Answer (score -1):

There are shorter versions, but this one "shows" each step.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=`grep 'Tests ' a | awk -F',' '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4}' | sed 's/ //g' | awk -F':' '{print $2}'`
echo $arr
for var in $arr
do
    echo $var
done
```

Comment: `declare -a` is not available in POSIX sh (as arrays aren't supported there in general).

Comment: ...also, `declare -a arr=$(...)` only assigns any value to _the first element of_ arr; it would need to be `declare -a arr=( $(...) )` to assign to multiple elements (using string-splitting and glob expansion to get to those elements from the single string received from the expansion -- rarely a desirable practice); alternately, with bash 4.x, `readarray` and `mapfile` are available to populate an array directly.

Comment: Also!  I need to do this in sh, unfortunately