# How to parse substrings with spaces into shell variables in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

**What we have:**

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678678/parsing-substrings-into-shell-variables-in-bash), the following pattern was suggested to recognize lines matching a pattern in bash, and extract parts of that line into shell variables:

```
re='^\[([[:digit:]:]+)\] \[Server thread/INFO\]: ([^[:space:]]+) entered area ~ ([^[:space:]]+) - [(]PvP[)] ~'
line='[18:51:10] [Server thread/INFO]: Tester121 entered area ~ Wilderness - (PvP) ~'

if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
  time=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  player=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  area=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

**However, that code doesn't work with a different where the content being matched can contain spaces.** Consider the following less-simplified format:

```
re='???'
line='[19:27:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Tester121 entered area ~ City - Leader Tester777 - (No PvP) ~'

if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
  time=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  player=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  area=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
  #leader="Tester777"
  leader=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
  #pvp="No PvP"
  pvp=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
fi
```

**What should be the `re` for it?** I am new to regex and try to learn.

Comment: It'd be ideal to show what you tried -- so not just a `re=???` placeholder, but specifically your own attempt at extending the regex.

Comment: ...btw, I tried to update the title to distinguish how this question is different from the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention "changes", I'm assuming you aren't supposed to match both cases. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So what about something like:

```
\[([[:digit:]:]+)\] \[Server thread/INFO\]: ([^[:space:]]+) entered area ~ ([^[:space:]]+) - Leader ([^[:space:]]+) - \(([^)]*)\) ~
```

You can see a [**live preview here**](https://regex101.com/r/OsWJS1/2).

> with spaces in it

The key here is `\(([^)]*)\)`. It matches everything within the parenthesis. This of course means that you can't have nested (close) parenthesis then.

Comment: That tester is using PCRE syntax, but the bash `=~` operator uses only ERE. One of the particular differences is that ERE doesn't support using `*?` to make the behavior of `*` non-greedy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ohh, didn't realize that!

Comment: As edited, this looks good to me -- as in, tests out successfully using `[[ $line =~ $re ]]` in bash.